# How to bind dropdownlist from database using c# and stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to know, what is the correct way to bind data on a drop down list from a database using stored procedure and C#. I have a drop down list `ddlEmployees` and an `Employee` table which has a column of `empFname` aswell as a stored procedure `selectEmployeePaycheck` which has a parameter of `@fname`, that matches the value in the `Employee` table which has a column of `empFname`. I'm using the code in the bottom to bind the data from database, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adr;
DataTable dt;
string conStr;

conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["payRollConnection"].ConnectionString;
con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("selectEmployeePayCheck", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ddlEmployees.SelectedValue);
adr = new SqlAdapter(cmd);
dt = new DataTable();
adr.Fill(dt);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataSource = dt;
ddlEmployees.DataBind();
cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

Any suggestions, corrections, answers are very well accepted.

Comment: When you say it does not work what is happening that should not be? Also, as a side note, be careful when using something like a first name to be your unique column. If you have 2 Johns working for you than you are going to get incorrect data returned. The best way usually is to have a unique id column in your database and use that to query, join etc.

Comment: I think problem is here.. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ddlEmployees.SelectedValue);` 

You're passing FName as unique value before binding any data to `ddlEmployees` ?

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor has made a valid point. Another issue I can sense is with the web design. You are trying to pass empFName to stored proc from ddlEmployees and the result you are binding to the same ddlEmployees. If you are expecting just one result from stored proc, use label or different controls. If multiple results are expected, use a different ddl to bind.

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor the drop down list does not bind the data from the database.

Comment: @RahulHendawe the "@fname" parameter is from the selectEmployeePayCheck procedure which is associated with the Employee Table

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking what do you suggest then?

Comment: @MrPericles do you expect multiple records or single record from from stored proc?

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking multiple records

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor has explained quite well. Check his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have made small modifications in your code, just replace it with this:

```
SqlConnection con; 
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter adr;
DataTable dt;
string conStr;

conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["payRollConnection"].ConnectionString;
using(con = new SqlConnection(conStr)) {
        using(cmd = new SqlCommand("selectEmployeePayCheck", con)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ddlEmployees.SelectedValue);
        // or cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ddlEmployees.SelectedText.ToString()); 
        // according to your query at the backend
        adr = new SqlAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adr.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

ddlEmployees.DataSource = dt;
ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataBind();
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by moving data source before field set, also you don't need excute reader here

```
adr.Fill(dt);
//cmd.ExecuteReader();
//set data source first
ddlEmployees.DataSource = dt;
ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "empFname";
ddlEmployees.DataBind();
```

Comment: `if (!IsPostBack)
{con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
   con.Open();
   cmd = new SqlCommand("selectContractorPayCheck", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ddlContractor.SelectedValue);
   adr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   dt = new DataTable();
   adr.Fill(dt);

   ddlContractor.DataSource = dt;
   ddlContractor.DataTextField = "conFname";
   ddlContractor.DataValueField = "conFname";
   ddlContractor.DataBind();
  }`

Comment: Can you update the quotation with your stored procedure code? Any exception you get?

Comment: This is the stored procedure that I use:
`create proc selectContractorPayCheck
@fname varchar(30)
as begin
select conFname from Contractor where conFname = @fname
end`
The exception that I get when I run the code block I recently changed is that the drop down list is not binding the data from the database..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments and the original question what I believe to be your scenario is the following:

You have an Employees table containing employee records and some sort of table that has paycheck details.

What you are trying to achieve is when the user selects an employee you show their paychecks in the dropdown?

If this is the case I would approach it as follows:

Use 2 dropdownlists, one for you employees and one for the paycheck records.

Use the code from Damiths answer to populate your employee dropdown. Make sure that this dropdown has autopostback enabled and that you hook into the selectedindexchanged event for this dropdown.

On the selected index changed event use your original code, using the ddlEmployee.selectedvalue, to get the selected employee and populate your paycheck dropdown.

Also, make sure that if you are populating your employee dropdown in the page_load event that you wrap it in

```
if(!isPostback)
{

}
```

otherwise the dropdown will repopulate on every postback, causing the salary records of the first employee to always be shown.

I hope this answers helps you to see the direction that you need to follow.